# How to add an intermediate certificate to a pfx file

Tags: ssl, certificate

I've been using a certificate that's stored on the server in a myserver.pfx file.

However, behavior is not the same in all browsers and some complain on account of, I think, a missing 'intermediate' certificate.

I've downloaded the intermediate certificate from Gandi: GandiStandardSSLCA.pem

Now, my question is, how can I add that intermediate certificate into the pfx file?

Although the server is windows, I'm trying to use openssl on a linux machine to manipulate the certificates, just because that's where I have openssl available. I'm assuming this doesn't matter.

One thing I've tried, is to use openssl to export myserver.pfx to myserver.pem, a text file. Then, with a text editor, I've added the text of GandiStandardSSLCA.pem to myserver.pem in hopes of then converting back to pfx format. However, I couldn't get openssl to do that conversion back to pfx.

Is this possible? If so, at the text editing stage, does it matter if the intermediate certificate text goes at the beginning or the end? Also, would I need to manufacture 'Bag Attributes' somehow?

Or, is the whole operation done in one line with openssl?

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that generates a new file. I'll experiment with the text order & see what works.

Comment: Following on from this, for anyone with the same problem: the Gandi intermediate certificate, when I looked inside the pem file, contained two BEGIN CERTIFICATE/END CERTIFICATE sections. Using a text editor to add that information to my existing pem file, at either the beginning or end of the existing text, converting to pfx, installing and checking with https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html, both worked. I just left the Bag Attributes as they were & didn't need to somehow create that information for the intermediate certificate I added.

Answer (score 5):

The .pfx file can be prepared by exporting the intermediate certificate .pem file with the below command example.

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile more.crt

Reference:
https://www.ssl.com/how-to/create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/

Comment: You can add `-name "star.domain.com-2022"` to include a named alias in the PFX for easier identification in some environments such as IIS.